# Rename columns in multiple dataframes, R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to rename columns of multiple `data.frame`s.

To give an example, let's say I've a list of `data.frame`s `dfA`, `dfB` and `dfC`. I wrote a function `changeNames` to set names accordingly and then used `lapply` as follows:

```
dfs <- list(dfA, dfB, dfC)
ChangeNames <- function(x) {
    names(x) <- c("A", "B", "C" )  
}
lapply(dfs, ChangeNames)
```

However, this doesn't work as expected. It seems that I am not assigning the new names to the `data.frame`, rather only creating the new names. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: After the line `names(x) <-` in your function, add `return(x)` or simply `x`. Else, you're returning just `names(x)`.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply Arun! If I ad return(x), I will get an outprint of dfA, dfB and dfC, with the new names. But if I view names(dfA), names(dfB) and names(dfC) afterwards, they still have the old column names. My data frames are also very large, so I am not interested in viewing them. Only changing there column names.

Comment: `lapply` does not modify the input. There's no "change by reference" happening here. Everything is being done on a copy. You'll have to assign the result back. do: `dfs <- lapply(dfs, ChangeNames)`

Comment: Ok, dfs is now one big list containing dfA, dfB and dfC, with the new columnnames. I am still interested in working with dfA, dfb an dfC individually, and individually they still have the old columnnames? How do I assign the result back to the individual dataframes?

Comment: well, you should assign them back. `dfA <- dfs[[1]]`... ?

Answer (score 16):

There are two things here:

- 1) You should return the value you want from your function. Else, the last value will be returned. In your case, that's `names(x)`. So, instead you should add as the final line, `return(x)` or simply `x`. So, your function would look like:

  ```
  ChangeNames <- function(x) {
      names(x) <- c("A", "B", "C" )
      return(x)
  }
  ```
- 2) `lapply` does not modify your input objects by reference. It works on a copy. So, you'll have to assign the results back. Or another alternative is to use `for-loops` instead of `lapply`:

  ```
  # option 1
  dfs <- lapply(dfs, ChangeNames)

  # option 2
  for (i in seq_along(dfs)) {
      names(dfs[[i]]) <- c("A", "B", "C")
  }
  ```

Even using the `for-loop`, you'll still make a copy (because `names(.) <- .` does). You can verify this by using `tracemem`.

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10, z=11:15)
tracemem(df)
# [1] "<0x7f98ec24a480>"
names(df) <- c("A", "B", "C")
tracemem(df)
# [1] "<0x7f98e7f9e318>"
```

If you want to modify by reference, you can use `data.table` package's `setnames` function:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10, z=11:15)
require(data.table)
tracemem(df)
# [1] "<0x7f98ec76d7b0>"
setnames(df, c("A", "B", "C"))
tracemem(df)
# [1] "<0x7f98ec76d7b0>"
```

You see that the memory location `df` is mapped to hasn't changed. The names have been modified by reference.

Comment: Using this as a function to change column names across multiple data frames contained in a list like this was incredibly helpful. I generalized the function to take a second and third argument, and used that as the input for a `grep()` to change names of specific columns within all of my data frames.

Answer (score 13):

If the dataframes were not in a list but just in the global environment, you could refer to them using a vector of string names.

```
dfs <- c("dfA", "dfB", "dfC")

for(df in dfs) {
  df.tmp <- get(df)
  names(df.tmp) <- c("A", "B", "C" ) 
  assign(df, df.tmp)
}
```

EDIT

To simplify the above code you could use

```
for(df in dfs)
  assign(df, setNames(get(df),  c("A", "B", "C")))
```

or using `data.table` which doesn't require reassigning.

```
for(df in c("dfA", "dfB"))
  data.table::setnames(get(df),  c("G", "H"))
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the problem of importing a public data set and having to rename each dataframe and rename each column in each dataframe to trim whitespaces, lowercase, and replace internal spaces with periods.

Combining the above methods got me:

```
for (eachdf in dfs)
  df.tmp <- get(eachdf) 
    for (eachcol in 1:length(df.tmp))
      colnames(df.tmp)[eachcol] <-
      str_trim(str_to_lower(str_replace_all(colnames(df.tmp)[eachcol], " ", ".")))
      }
  assign(eachdf, df.tmp) 
}
```