# Loop through column names in multiple datasets to fix name discrepancy

Tags: r

I have multiple data sets that are the same column structure but different row lengths. When I go to stack them, there is an occasional problem with `rbind` as one file may have the column names uppercase whereas another may have lowercase. I would like to run something at the beginning that converts everything to lowercase (as this is not case sensitive).

When I do the following one-off, the conversion works. However, I am messing something up trying to do this through a loop.

**This works**

```
names(fmli3) <- tolower(names(fmli3))
```

**Does not work**

```
df_qtr <- c(fmli1, fmli2, fmli3, fmli4, fmli5)

for (i in 1:length(df_qtr)){
  names(df_qtr[[i]]) <- tolower(names(df_qtr[[i]]))
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to JWilliman answer in the [cross post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375969/rename-columns-in-multiple-dataframes-r) (and Shea for pointing out), the following works:

```
dfs <- c("fmli1", "fmli2", "fmli3", "fmli4", "fmli5")

for(df in dfs) {
  df.tmp <- get(df)
  names(df.tmp) <- tolower(names(df.tmp)) 
  assign(df, df.tmp)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename columns in multiple dataframes, R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375969/rename-columns-in-multiple-dataframes-r)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with original code is that `df_qtr` is not a list of 5 `data.frame`. You can check `length(df_qtr)` to verify.

Use the following syntax to connect multiple `data.frame` into a `list`.

```
 df_qtr <- list( fmli1, fmli2, ...)
```