# Renaming the same column in multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I have three dataframes with one variable but it is labelled differently in each. Is there a way to rename the variable by position (or just by the dataframes each having a single variable) across all three dataframes rather than doing it individually.

e.g I would like to rename the column in `dfa`, `dfb`, `dfc` to "Percentage"

```
dfa <- data.frame(x = c(45, 55))

dfb <- data.frame(y = c(60, 40))

dfc <- data.frame(z = c(30, 70))
```

I tried using a loop like below - why doesn't this work?

```
for (i in c(dfa, dfb, dfc)) {
names(i)[1] <- "Percentage"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375969/rename-columns-in-multiple-dataframes-r)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `purrr` and `dplyr` libraries:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

list2env(purrr::imap(list(dfa = dfa, dfb = dfb, dfc = dfc), ~ dplyr::rename(., Percentage = 1)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Or using pipes you can write this as

```
list(dfa = dfa, dfb = dfb, dfc = dfc) %>% 
  purrr::imap(~ dplyr::rename(., Percentage = 1)) %>%
  list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

---

**How it works**

1. If you put your dataframes into a list with the same names (ie `dfa = dfa`) then `purrr::imap` will apply a function over that list and preserve the names. The output of `imap` will be a list where element names are still `dfa, dfb, dfc`. This will be useful in step 3.
2. The function being mapped over the list is `dplyr::rename`, which you can use positionally. Here `Percentage = 1` is renaming the first column to be "Percentage".
3. Lastly, `list2env` will unlist the dataframes into your global environment with the same names.

---

You could do something similar in base `R`:

```
# names(x)[1] <- "Percentage" renames first column
list_of_dfs <- lapply(list(dfa, dfb, dfc), function(x) { 
  names(x)[1] <- "Percentage"
  x})

names(list_of_dfs) <- c("dfa", "dfb", "dfc")
list2env(list_of_dfs, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```